# How to use function argument type for new function argument type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I've created a custom action creator function, which generates an action creator for the redux using a reducer map. It works fine, but the issue here is I don't want to pass payload type for action creator. It should pick from the reducer action type.

**Typing should also pick from reducerMap.**

let's say action

```
updateAge(state: SomeType, age: number)

UserActions.updateAge("9"); // this should give an error
```

Code:

```
type SomeType = {
  age: number;
};

const userState: SomeType = {
  age: 0,
};

const userReducerMap = {
  updateAge(state: SomeType, age: number): SomeType {
    return {
      ...state,
      age,
    };
  },
};
export const userReducer = (state = userState, action: any): SomeType => {
  const { type, payload } = action;
  const reducer = userReducerMap[type];
  if (reducer) {
    return reducer(state, payload);
  }
  return state;
};

// Another File
export type ActionCreator<A> = {
  [key in keyof A]: <T>(payload: T) => {
    type: key;
    payload: T;
  };
};

const generateActionCreator = <X>(reducers: X) =>
  Object.keys(reducers).reduce((acc, type) => {
    const x = reducers[type];
    acc[type] = (payload): { type: string; payload: Object } => ({
      type,
      payload,
    });
    x;
    return acc;
  }, {} as ActionCreator<X>);

export const UserActions =
  generateActionCreator<typeof userReducerMap>(userReducerMap);

// Problem
UserActions.updateAge(9); // Valid
UserActions.updateAge("9"); // Should give error
```

Comment: Missing definitions for `userReducerMap` and `reducers`. If these are too complicated, just give us their types. You can also add a playground defining these with `declare const userReducerMap: WhateverTypeItIs;`.

Comment: userReducerMap is added